# File output with loop check and try catch block

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, fileoutputstream

Having a bit of trouble with file outputs and using try/catch. I'm trying to basically say that if the user inputs an existing filename, keep looping until valid filename is entered. However, i cant seem to get it to work. Any hints on where im going wrong? Tried moving the initial prompt around try block but wouldnt that make the scope only available in the try block? So essentially, i should have the prompt outside so its available to all the try/catch blocks? Not sure though.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;  
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 public class TestAccountWithException 
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

    // variable declaration
    String fileName;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double balance;
    int id = 1122;
    final double RATE = 4.50;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter file name: ");
    fileName = input.next();
    File fw = new File(fileName);

    try 
        {

            // check if file already exists
            while(fw.exists()) 
            {
                System.out.print("File already exists. Enter valid file name: ");
                fileName = input.next();
                fw = new File(fileName);
            }   


            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
            firstName = input.next();

            System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
            lastName = input.next();

            System.out.print("Input beginnning balance: ");
            balance = input.nextDouble();   

            // pass object to printwriter and use pw to write to the file
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

            // print to created file
            pw.println(firstName);
            pw.println(lastName);
            pw.println(balance);
            pw.println(id);
            pw.println(RATE);
            pw.close();
            //      System.out.print("Run program? (1) Yes (2) No: ");
            //      cont = input.nextInt();


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    } // end main
  } // end class
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to use `java.nio.file`. With this java 7 package, you can use as

```
while(true) {
  String fileName = input.next();
  Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
  if (Files.exists(path)) {
     try {
     // file exists 
     // your operations
     } catch {

     }
     break;
   } else {
      // not found
      fileName = input.next();
   }
 }
```

Comment: @javaaaaaa  Your code is running can you specify if you got any error.